# BTC sent from blockchain.info to BCH wallet on coinbase by mistake

Tags: blockchain.info, coinbase.com

I m quite a newbie in crypto. On Dec 21st by mistake i sent 2BTC from my blockchain.info wallet to my Coinbase BCH wallet. Quite an honest mistake as they just had implemented BCH page and i didn’t realise i m taking BCH address. I have contacted them many times and they refuse to assist me with recovering them. Is there anyway that i can retrieve those coins? Much appreciate your help with this.
I have read answers about similar cases but my question is specific to Coinbase. Has there ever been a case where coinbase assisted with recovery? Do they have any policy that takes into account the amount of transaction or they refuse to help in any case?

Answer (score 1):

I have done exactly the same thing on Dec 23rd.  I only received a generic response that transactions are irreversible.  But I read of others that have had success from transactions >$5K  which both of ours qualify.  If it wasn't Coinbase the simple solution is to use the private key to put the coin back in a BTC wallet.  But since this is an exchange we are at the mercy of Coinbase to retrieve those private keys and deposit them into our equivalent Coinbase BTC wallets.  If you happen to get a response or a next step to resolution please post the solution.

Comment: Thanks I have read similar things. I m just wondering if Coinbase ever helped anyone in this situation. Given the materiality if transaction. Please let me know as well if you get any success.